# Why go-jaeger-client requires wrappers for metrics and logs?

Tags: go, opentracing, jaeger

I’ve started with instrumenting my gRPC service using go-gRPC-middleware. I’ve got logs working using zap and metrics exposed for Prometheus.

Now that I’m trying to configure tracing using jaeger go client it requires me to add wrapper around metrics storage and logger. I’m not sure I understand why those wrappers are required

https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/blob/bf64373d1e690594fd8c279720faf32722cf1494/examples/hotrod/pkg/tracing/init.go#L46

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jaeger clients are designed to have a minimum set of dependencies. We don't know if your application is using Prometheus metrics or Zap logger. This is why `jaeger-client-go` (as well as many other Jaeger clients in other languages) provide two lightweight interfaces for a Logger and MetricsFactory that can be implemented for a specific logs/metrics backend that your application is using. Of course, the bindings for Prometheus and Zap are already implemented in the `jaeger-lib` and can be included optionally.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind it to metrics and logging frameworks, but you don't have to. You can simply just call `cfg.NewTracer()`, like in this example:

```golang
func ExampleFromEnv() {
    cfg, err := jaegercfg.FromEnv()
    if err != nil {
        // parsing errors might happen here, such as when we get a string where we expect a number
        log.Printf("Could not parse Jaeger env vars: %s", err.Error())
        return
    }

    tracer, closer, err := cfg.NewTracer()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Could not initialize jaeger tracer: %s", err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer closer.Close()

    opentracing.SetGlobalTracer(tracer)
    // continue main()
}
```

Source: https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-go/blob/3585cc566102e0ea2225177423e3fcc3d2e5fd7a/config/example_test.go#L88-L105

Check the Jaeger Go Client readme for more information on the metrics/logging integration: https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-go

Comment: Thanks for your response. I assume binding it to metrics and logging is very useful, allowing to go logs <-> tracing <-> metrics. `jaeger-client-go` is what I'm using. I've got tracing working separately but I'd like to establish binding. My confusing comes from the fact that I can't pass `*zap.Logger` and `*prometheus.Registry`  into `cfg.NewTracer(config.Logger(...))` for `jaeger-client-go`. Instead, I need to wrap it into a simplified logger and some metrics factory as per `hotrod` example. I'm new to this system and wondering why is it required.